# CORS blocked access even though the local address is allowed in server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, entity-framework

I have an Angular page which is making use of an Entity Framework powered ASP.NET server. Both Angular and ASP.NET applications run on different local addresses. To prevent CORS errors, I have configured some settings at the server side.

At the ASP.NET side, in **WebApiConfig.cs** I have enabled all of the access permissions from the Angular local address with this;

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

However, when I trying to **Edit** a value from the Angular page, I am still having the CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:62677/Assets/Edit/177738ba-16cd-4b08-b339-974f0547e626' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Inserting a new value to the database or getting all of the values from the database is working without the CORS error but editing an existing value gives an error.

I tried to add a break-point at the above code in **WebApiConfig.cs** and debug it, however, line of code is never reached.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

**Addition:** Also I have the following configurations in my **Web.config** file;

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

**New ERROR after implementing Shyam Vemula's solution:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:62677/Assets/Edit/177738ba-16cd-4b08-b339-974f0547e626' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

Comment: update this line to config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(" * ", headers: " * ", methods: " * ")); and then check

Comment: @HiteshAnshani, CORS is still blocking the access.

Comment: I think, you have to add `Application_BeginRequest` Method in `Global.asmx` page.

Comment: @ShyamVemula, I checked the `Global.asax` and the `WebApiConfig.register()` method is not called there. Can that be the issue?

Comment: Localhost is not a good test, it will always give u the error. try to publish your project and have a name to the ip. you could ping the ip masking to a local name in the host file.

Comment: remove everything and add this line before the controller method   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // tune to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Add the following in `Global.asmx`

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var response = context.Response;

    // enable CORS
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        response.End();
    }
}
```

and Remove this from `Web.config` file

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

Comment: I have a CORS error still, but the error is slightly changed now. I am adding to the question the new error, please check.

Comment: Have u removed the `CustomHeaders` from `Web.config`

Comment: Yes, I did. Please check the new error in question. Spesificially look at the last part of the error.

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Edited the Answer. Check once.

Comment: CORS error is dissapeared! Thanks so much. However, the value is not edited, I think I need to debug server side application.

Comment: I am having the following exceptions;`System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Web.dll` Can that be about the `response`?